# Why am I unable to create Boto3 S3 client instance in Airflow 2.5 (task gets stuck without error)? How to debug it?

Tags: python, macos, airflow, boto3

When I try to create a Boto3 client instance (e.g., `s3 = boto3.client('s3')`), the Airflow task gets stuck. It doesn't end or get timed out or even throw any error.

Questions:

1. How do I debug this?
2. Which environment variables / files should I ensure exist?

More info:

- The task doesn't remain in scheduled / queued state. It is in running state (green bar).
- This is only happening in latest version of Airflow (2.5). I ran similar code in an older version (2.1.2) which works fine.

Task instance log:

```
*** Reading local file: ...
...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2023-04-03, 10:13:15 IST] {taskinstance.py:1283} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
...
[2023-04-03, 10:13:15 IST] {task_command.py:388} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: check_boto3_connection.check manual__2023-04-03T04:43:09.385235+00:00 [running]> on ...
[2023-04-03, 10:13:15 IST] {taskinstance.py:1509} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=check_boto3_connection
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=check
...
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=1
...
[2023-04-03, 10:13:15 IST] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - Creating Boto3 client...
```

The full DAG:

```py
import datetime

import boto3
import botocore.client
from airflow.decorators import dag, task


@dag(schedule=None, start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 4, 1), catchup=False)
def check_boto3_connection():
    check()


@task
def check():
    print('Creating Boto3 client...')
    s3 = boto3.client(
        's3',
        config=botocore.client.Config(
            connect_timeout=5,
            retries={'max_attempts': 0},
        ),
    )
    print('S3 client:', s3)


check_boto3_connection()
```

Answer (score 0):

It was mostly because of running Airflow on Mac M1 (so many apps have problems running on it without bugs).

Related GitHub issue: [Task exited with return code Negsignal.SIGSEGV when dag triggered from UI #24463](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/24463)

Workaround: add `NO_PROXY=*` environment variable.

How I ran:

```
$ export NO_PROXY=*
$ airflow scheduler # and also, `airflow webserver` in another terminal
```

**Caution**: most likely not good for production environments.